# Multiple background images within same css class having different z-index

Tags: html, css, background-image, z-index

I could be going about this totally wrong. I'm creating a website using images I've sliced from a .PSD file that a graphic artist designed. In a nut shell the background image consists of 4 green bars angled 45 deg slightly woven in with 3 blue bars angled 315 deg so they cross at the edges.

Picture the pattern as follows with the edges overlapping

```
/ z-index: 0
\ z-index: 1
/ z-index: 0
\ z-index: 1
/ z-index: 0
\ z-index: 1
/ z-index: 0
```

I need four of the bars to appear below the other three bars. Eventually the goal is to animate these bars so that as you scroll up or down the page they will raise or lower. So I need each bar to be a separate element, div or whatever it needs to be rather than a flattened image. The problem is when you have multiple background-images you can't use the z-index, z-index only works with each element individually. I could assign a z-index if I had a separate div for each background-image.

Each of these images is about 1284px width, 769px height. I'm not against having each background image in its own div. But when I do that it doesn't seem to work. Can I have multiple div's each having its own background image? When I include a z-index in the css class below I'm not able to assign a z value with each background image. Otherwise if I could assign a z-index for each background image in the class below my code would work for what I'm trying to achieve.

```
<code>
<div class="stripes">

</div>

.stripes {
    position: relative;
    background-image: url(/images/GreenOne_49_01.png),
                      url(/images/BlueOne_49_02.png),
                      url(/images/GreenTwo_49_03.png),
                      url(/images/BlueTwo_49_03.png),
                      url(/images/GreenThree_49_04.png),
                      url(/images/BlueThree_49_05.png),
                      url(/images/GreenFour_49_05.png);
    background-position: 0px 0px,
                         0px 690px,
                         0px 690px,
                         0px 1378px,
                         0px 1384px,
                         0px 2075px,
                         0px 2076px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;  

}
<code>
```

Comment: can you share a fiddle of your example?

Comment: Just a suggestion here, but it seems to me like you're trying to go for something that modifies the z-index on scroll? With background images this isn't really an option. I'm sure if you felt adamant enough you could get some javascript to continuously redeclare the background image property with all of your urls, since they're technically "z-indexed" dependent upon the order you declare them in, writing code that will redeclare these images in a different order might be what you need!

Answer (score 0):

As Morklympious mentioned, you'll need to use javascript to alter the class/id of the elements within your code. Once you do that, you can modify the css' new class/id to the background/color that you want.

Watch how these elements come into view as the user scrolls down: http://www.htmlpanda.com/skills-meter.php

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp

Comment: Yeah using JavaScript/jQuery to make that happen seems to be the way to go. Thanks for the example and resource link. I like how htmlpanda has the elements scroll in and out from the side as you scroll up and down the webpage. I'm going to try to mimic what they are doing to have mine work in a similar way.